# Animating GeoJSON or KML file in Cesium

Tags: cesium

https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=GeoJSON%20and%20TopoJSON.html

I just saw the custom style part of this example.

I made a part of a region into a realm.

https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=CZML%20Custom%20Properties.html&label=CZML

I want to adjust the height in real time like in this link.

I’m starting Cesium now, so I’m still lacking.

Can you tell me how to do it?